# What is the best alternative for heredocs that allows to insert PHP code inside variable?

Tags: php

I have a stupid problem :) I have some block's of code and I would like to reuse them again. I don't want to use include and create a lot of files but keep everything in one file in variables and then just echo them whatever I want.

I paste below the simple example of code that I want to put in variable.

```
<div class="block">
    <a class="header" href="#">ABC <span>KASZMIR</span></a>
    <?php links('0', $product); ?>
    <?php links('1', $product); ?>
    <?php links('2', $product); ?>
    <?php links('3', $product); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: [Functions!](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Answer (score 1):

May make a function of it:

```
$myFunction = function($args) {

  return "<div class=\"block\">
    <a class=\"header\" href=\"#\">ABC <span>KASZMIR</span></a>
    ".links('0', $args)."
    ".links('2', $args)."
    ".links('3', $args)."
    ".links('4', $args)."
</div>";

};
echo $myFunction($product);
```